# process.exit hook infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the native exit hook for exiting a Node.js process:

```
process.on('exit', function () { // listen to exit event

});
```

this hook will be invoked directly by calling

```
process.exit();  // probably does some magic to remove calls from queue somehow, somewhere in the Node.js process
```

However, I have seen some code out there online that recommends doing this:

```
process.on('exit', function () {
  if (condition) {
    process.exit(1); // will this invoke the same exit event?
  } else {
    process.exit(0); // will this invoke the same exit event?
  }
});
```

My question is, will the `process.exit` call inside the hook ever cause any problems with an infinite call stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.exit` has a flag called `process._exiting`. So, if the flag is set, then the `process`'s `exit` event will not be emitted anymore.

This is how [`process.exit`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.1.0/src/node.js#L754-L763) looks like, as of Node.js v5.1.0,

```
process.exit = function(code) {
  if (code || code === 0)
    process.exitCode = code;

  if (!process._exiting) {
    process._exiting = true;
    process.emit('exit', process.exitCode || 0);
  }
  process.reallyExit(process.exitCode || 0);
};
```

---

If you like to mess around, then try this

```
var counter = 0;

process.on('exit', function (val) {
  console.log("Counter", counter++);
  if (counter === 2) {
    console.log("Really exiting now");
    // change this to `false` if you want to see infinite loop :D
    process._exiting = true;
  } else {
    process._exiting = false;
  }
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call process.exit() (and optionally pass in an exit code), you cause processing to stop. The exit event is fired, which is the last opportunity for any code to run, and the event loop is stopped. Shortly thereafter Node.js actually stops completely and returns the specified exit code. So process.exit() stops Node.js from doing anything tangible after that point and the application stops.